# How to call java servlet's doGet method from smack library's packetlistener?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, smack

I'm using smack library to receive messages from my android application to the server.
Below is my code:

```
     String username=this.GCM_SENDER_ID+"@gcm.googleapis.com";
     String password=this.GCM_SERVER_KEY;

     config = new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
     config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
     config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
     config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
     config.setSendPresence(false);
     config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
     config.setDebuggerEnabled(false);

     connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
     connection.connect();

     connection.addConnectionListener(new AppConnectionListener());
     connection.addPacketListener(new AppPacketListener(),new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));
     connection.addPacketInterceptor(new AppPacketInterceptor(), new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

     connection.login(username, password);
```

Now, when a new message receives at the server, AppPacketListener is called. 
What i want is to call a java servlet's doGet method or to send a get request to some other jsp page.
How do i do it?? any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to call the servlet from your java client. By default the `doGet` method will be called if you call your servlet(i.e. http://myhost.com/myservlet).

From [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html):

```
 InputStream response = new URL("http://myhost.com/myservlet").openStream();
```